# put an image on an anchor tag

Tags: html, css

I have an `ul` like below which has anchor tags.

```
<ul class="nav-link-bottom">
        <li><a class="active"  href="login.html">Existing user</a></li>
        <li><a href="signup.html" style = "background-color:#000">new user</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to place an image on the second anchor tag. Not sure how I can do that.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bsbk3bgq/). And the [image](http://oi67.tinypic.com/2m43ehd.jpg) I want to put on the left anchor same position as the caret you see.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_links_image

Answer (score 16):

Don't really understand you question but if you want the `img` to serve as `link`, you could do

```
<a href="page.html"><img src="img.png"></a>
```

And then give the `anchor tag` what ever `height` or `width`

Answer (score 2):

```
<li><a href=""><img src="" alt=""></a></li>
```